# How to edit DateEdit input format

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

How can i change the input format of the DateEdit? I want to type 2012 for example
without day and month.

With the display format i can change the it after enter a date. 
So i thought the edit format is the solution.

But if i type
 `editformat.formatstring = "yyyy"` 
and i try to type 2012 in the dateedit i just get 0001 as display text after enter it.

Furthermore is it possible to type the month only? For example type 10 and he display October.

regards

Comment: better you can use textbox, why your using the datetime control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. With the EditMask it is possible to change the display and edit style of an dateedit.

```
   DevExpress.XtraEditors.DateEdit myDateEdit= new DevExpress.XtraEditors.DateEdit();
    ...    
   myDateEdit.Properties.EditMask = "y";
```

will show November 2012 for example.

The Property is located at myDateEdit.Properties.EditMask
It belongs to the Devexpress DateEdit!

Comment: Please elaborate more. Where is this property located

Comment: which version of devexpress are you using ?

Comment: can u please apply in this :-->  <dx:ASPxDateEdit runat="server" ID="dateeditor" DisplayFormatString="MMM/yyyy" AutoPostBack="true" OnDateChanged="dateeditor_DateChanged"></dx:ASPxDateEdit>

Comment: @tusharnarang iam using version v.10.2 and winforms. Iam not using asp!

Comment: oh ok thats the reason I am not able to find that property

Answer (score 0):

Though this question has been asked a couple of times already, take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)
probably what you want is:

```
string date1 = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy");
```

Comment: thanks a lot but that isnt what i mean. I want that the user cant type days and month in the dateedit. Just the year. In further case he should just type month and year without day. Maybe textedit is better solution.